# Suma de elementos de una pila en Java

Tags: java, pilas

Estoy tratando de hacer la función `sumaEnFondoPila()` en el que tengo que sumar todos los elementos de una pila y poner su resultado en el fondo de esa pila.

Por ejemplo: si introduzco la pila `[1,2,3,4]` tengo que hacer que me devuelva `[1,2,3,4,10]`

Este es mi desarrollo de la función, pero no consigo hacer que funcione. ¿Qué tendría que modificar?

```
public void sumaEnFondoPila(Pila pila) {
    int suma = 0;
    if(!pila.vacia()){
        int elemento = pila.desapilar();
        suma += pila.desapilar();
        sumaEnFondoPila(pila);
        pila.apilar(elemento);
    }else{
        pila.apilar(suma);
    }
}
```

Comment: puede colocar el código de la clase Pila

Answer (score 0):

Te dejo un pequeño ejemplo para que veas como se puede realizar lo que quieres:

Declaramos una pila (stack) y le anadimos loa valores que desees.

```
Stack<Integer> pila = new Stack<Integer>();     
    
pila.push(1);
pila.push(2);
pila.push(3);
pila.push(4);
```

Hasta aquí tenemos la pila con los valores iniciales. Ahora recorremos dicha pila, sumamos sus valores y los guardamos en una variable. Después añadimos ese valor a la ultima posición de la pila:

```
int sum = 0;
for (Integer integer : pila) {
    sum += integer;
}
    
pila.push(sum);
```

Por ultimo, mostramos la pila:

```
for (Integer integer : pila) {
    System.out.println(integer);
}
```

**Output:**

```
1
2
3
4
10
```